# How to concat header, footer, and list of content files in gulp?

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I am making a html generator with a header file, a footer file, and list of content files. I have folder structure partials/contents. Inside partials folder is the header and footer, and in partials/contents are files like index.html, about-us.html, etc. In those content files, I want to add header and footer. So basically, I want to concatenate files by looping in the the contents folder as my content, and add header/footer files, then output in the different folder. How do I achieve that? Or you can suggest a folder structure to easily achieve this.

Here, what I have is gulp task for single file only in contents folder:

```js
gulp.task('html-test', ['clean-html-test'], function() {
  var header = './partials/header.html';
  var body = './partials/contents/_test.html';
  var footer = './partials/footer.html';
  var outputFilename = 'test.html';

  log('Generating public/test.html...');

  return gulp.src([header, body, footer])
    .pipe($.concat(outputFilename))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});
```

So, how can I automate that looping inside the contents folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, a gulp plugin called [gulp-headerfooter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-headerfooter). Just tested it and it worked!

```js
gulp.task('html-gen', function () {
  log('Generating html files...');
  gulp.src('./partials/content/*.html')
    .pipe($.headerfooter.header('./partials/_header.html'))
    .pipe($.headerfooter.footer('./partials/_footer.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});
```

Comment: Found another alternative by using gulp-inject: https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject#injecting-files-contents